# 'Get Unconsumed total From Corda Vault'

Tags: java, blockchain, corda

*I'm having some problems getting the new total after a token has been redeemed. So for instance, if I create and issue a token for the amount of 300, then redeem 100 tokens, I'd expect the vault query to give me a result of 200 when I query for unconsumed tokens. Instead, I get 300.*

*Here's my code:*

```
public final class TestFlow {
    private TestFlow() {}

    @Data
    @StartableByRPC
    @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    public static final class FindCurrencyByAccountIdAndCurrencyNameFlow extends FlowLogic < StateAndRef < CurrencyTokenType >> {
        @NonNull
        String accountId;
        @NonNull
        String currencyName;
        Vault.StateStatus vaultStatus;

        @Override
        @Suspendable
        public StateAndRef < CurrencyTokenType > call() throws FlowException {
            val accountService = getServiceHub().cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class);
            val account = Objects.requireNonNull(accountService.accountInfo(UUID.fromString(accountId))).getState().getData();
            val anonymousParty = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(account));
            val search = createQuery(account, anonymousParty, vaultStatus);

            return getServiceHub()
                .getVaultService()
                .trackBy(CurrencyTokenType.class, search.getCriteria(), search.getPageSpec(), search.getSorting())
                .getSnapshot()
                .getStates()
                .stream()
                .filter(it - > it.getState().getData().getName().equals(StringUtils.capitalize(currencyName)))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        }
    }

    private static SearchQuery createQuery(final AccountInfo account, final AnonymousParty anonymousParty, final Vault.StateStatus vaultStatus) {
        val contractStateTypes = ImmutableSet.of(CurrencyTokenType.class);
        val vaultCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(vaultStatus, contractStateTypes);

        val linearIds = ImmutableList.of(account.getIdentifier());
        val dealParty = ImmutableList.of(anonymousParty);
        val dealCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(dealParty, null);
        val linearCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(dealParty, linearIds, vaultStatus, null);
        val dealOrLinearIdCriteria = dealCriteria.or(linearCriteria);
        val criteria = dealOrLinearIdCriteria.and(vaultCriteria);

        val pageSpec = new PageSpecification(1, 10);
        val sortByUid = new Sort.SortColumn(new SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.LinearStateAttribute.UUID), Sort.Direction.DESC);
        val sorting = new Sort(ImmutableSet.of(sortByUid));

        return new SearchQuery(criteria, sorting, pageSpec);
    }

    @Data
    @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private static class SearchQuery {
        @NonNull
        QueryCriteria criteria;
        @NonNull
        Sort sorting;
        @NonNull
        PageSpecification pageSpec;
    }
}
```

*I must be missing something in the documentation because I haven't been able to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

Just based on this example there might be a couple of pieces you're a little confused on.

To be clear you'd want to have code that's doing just a query in a separate file. Updating tokens in a transaction will be finalized after the flow is completed. Maybe defining some of these functions you've created as separate flows will make it easier to clarify and separate the order of operations.

Take a look at samples-kotlin for some examples of kotlin apps using tokens.

https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Tokens

Specifically you'll want to look over this example of a token being used as a marker for paying dividends which should help you find the issue.

https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Tokens/stockpaydividend/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/stockpaydividend/flows/PayDividend.kt

Comment: "Thanks for the correspondence. How would that correlate with using the accounts lib? That's where I'm confused"